# How to Get Response From URL using Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, html, dom-events

I am doing phone gap application for that I will get response from this url

**http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp**.

I don't know how to get response can any one help me with code?

Comment: using http requests, look it up

Comment: can you make an ajax request ??

Answer (score 0):

If your application needs to connect to that from another website you can use JSONP

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

That is if you know that that the uname_validation.asp supports JSONP

If your page is on the same domain (http://www.apexweb.co.in) then you can use xmlhttprequest.

Both are made very easy and compatible with almost every browser out there using jQuery $.getJSON:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Here is an example connecting to google:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q="
     +"someting&callback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

Note that your asp should have a response header that sets contentType to application/javascript and generate valid JSONP (my asp is a but rusty so here is some pseudo code):

```
request("callback")&"("&jsonString&");"
```

Comment: can u explain a little more

Comment: Sure, first could you tell me if your page will be on http://www.apexweb.co.in or on another site? And do you have control over the output of http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp?

Comment: I am doing another MobileApp, for that i will use apex link for validation, if i get response as "sucees" i will redirect to next page (OR) in case of "Fail" i wil put one alert like invalid details

Answer (score 0):

using ajax in javascript can get the response.

```
var invocation = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://www.apexweb.co.in/apex_quote/uname_validation.asp';

function checkURL(){
        invocation.open('GET', url, true);
        invocation.onreadystatechange = handler;
        invocation.send(); 
}

function handler(evtXHR){
    if (invocation.readyState == 4)
    {
            if (invocation.status == 200)
            {
                //success
            }
            else {
                //failure
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: i am not getting response

Comment: please check this modifief answer..

Comment: thanx for ur answer but i am not getting response